# Separated Mvc controller in single UI view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two class library project and an mvc Web UI project like this.

- Separated.Blog.Controller (includes HomeController, index view)
- Separated.Admin.Controller (includes HomeController, index view)
- Separated.UI (includes Blog and Admin references)

I configured UI Route config like this.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("Blog", 
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
        new {controller="Home", action = "Index",id = UrlParameter.Optional },
          new[] { "Separated.Blog.Controller" });

        routes.MapRoute("Admin",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new{controller="Home",action="Index",id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "Separated.Admin.Controller" });

    }

namespace Separated.Admin.Controller.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController:System.Web.Mvc.Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content("This is Admin index page");
        }

    }
}
namespace Separated.Blog.Controller.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController: System.Web.Mvc.Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content("This is Blog index page...");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run project, gives error as following:

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This
>   can happen if the route that services this request
>   ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search
>   for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case,
>   register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method
>   that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.
>
> The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:
>   Separated.Admin.Controller.Controllers.HomeController
>   Separated.Blog.Controller.Controllers.HomeController

**I want to start up with Blog Home controller like localhost/Home/Index. And call Admin controller localhost/Admin/Home/Index**

Comment: You are looking for areas: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Think you should search for `Areas`

Comment: I added two area in UI project, They have controller and view folders. How can I show my separated controller to these areas?

Answer (score 0):

**Every Area has it's own AreaRegistration class.There you need to make change and set your controller action.**

This how you call for Area's controller action

```
'@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller", new { Area="YourAreaName"})'
```